# Simulating textbox edit action in javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I would like to know how to simulate a text box edit action in javascript. Basically, I need to edit a text box through code and would like all the correspoding text box java script events fired just like they do when a user manually does the update.

Here's a simple of code I have been working with. Clicking the 'Submit' button sets the value of the text box to 'Test'. I would then like the corresponding onkeyup event be automatically triggered.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hello(event) {
var fromElement = event.target;
alert(fromElement.value);
}
function handleClick() {
var tE = document.getElementById("tarea");
tE.value = "Test";
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="tarea" name="tarea" value="" onKeyUp="hello(event)"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="handleClick()">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To trigger the `onkeyup` event you can simply call it, it's a function:

`tE.onkeyup();`

Comment: Hi...I do not want to call the onkeyup manually...I would like it to be automatically invoked just like it does when a user tries to edit the text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `onkeyup()` method of your input field.